# How autonomous are commercial passenger airliners?

Tags: autopilot

Average layman here. Assuming the latest generation of planes/avionics rolling out of the factory today, how autonomous are commercial passenger jets? Obviously, autopilot has been around for decades, but what are the limits of its capabilities? Can it take off and land by itself? What can be done remotely, if anything?

Watching a typical airliner-crew-is-dead-what-can-we-do-now movie caused me to think of this question.

Comment: Hello iMerchant and welcome to aviation.SE. Your question seems too broad to me. What are you asking? [If the autopilot has taken up a significant amount of pilot duties](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2866/878)? [If a passenger plane can be remotely controlled](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1802/878)? [What happens if both pilots are incapacitated](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11677/878)?

Comment: You may be interested in [the `autoland` tag](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autoland).

Comment: See also [Has there ever been a fully automated takeoff, cruise, and landing of a large aircraft similar to commercial airliners?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/31464/753) and [How does auto landing work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23144/753)

Comment: Voting to keep open, mainly because this question (and the answers) focus on the difference between automated and autonomous.  The other questions focus somewhat more narrowly on specific autopilot capabilities, while this question looks at the broader issue.

Answer (score 9):

They're not really autonomous, they're mostly automated.

I'll lift this description from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_car) despite being written for cars (emphasis mine):

> Autonomous means self-governance. Many historical projects related to vehicle autonomy have been automated (made to be automatic) due to a heavy reliance on artificial hints in their environment, such as magnetic strips. **Autonomous control implies satisfactory performance under significant uncertainties in the environment and the ability to compensate for system failures without external intervention**.

While most autopilots will fare fairly well under "significant uncertainties in the environment" (read e.g. "severe turbulence"), they are not equally capable "to compensate for system failures without external intervention". Even the Airbus' autopilots revert authority to the pilots if the system degrades.

Even knowing the destination airport, they need a pilot to insert the flight plan into the flight computer, they cannot compute it by themselves.

They cannot take evasive action in case of dangerous situations, but they can only warn the pilot (see EGPWS and TCAS RAs).

They cannot even properly recognize bad weather (say, a thunderstorm) and eventually plan diversions around it.

They could not land an aircraft by themselves, as [they generally lack control](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26703/1467) over the aircraft configuration.

What they can do is blindly follow the flight plan given, so they are automatic, but not autonomous.

Comment: Good stuff but I disagree on the landing comment. [Auto-land capabilities  has been around since the days of the Concorde](http://www.concordesst.com/autopilot.html)

Comment: @Dave that's still automatic, not autonomous: the autopilot cannot negotiate a landing clearance, it cannot initiate a go-around in case of emergency, it cannot lower flaps and gear, it cannot select an alternate airport in case of need (and cannot recognize the case of need), it cannot land without the ILS antenna, i.e. it **relies on artificial hints in their environment**. It is automatic, not autonomous.

Comment: I will agree with that but strictly speaking they can land by them selves if set up properly

Comment: @Dave "if set up properly". That's the point. It's not autonomous if it needs "set up", and if it is not autonomous, is not strictly "by themselves".

Comment: I think the distinction here between autonomous and automatic is a little arbitrary. The case in point being that TCAS **has** been integrated into AP already (e.g. the A380).  Other feats like one-engine-out compensation, complex RNAV approaches, pitch-up overspeed protection, windshear modes, radios that identify the station, and emergency descent modes would be seen 60 years ago as amazing feats of computer decision-making.

Comment: @CodyP the TCAS integration is currently the exception, not the rule, and I wrote "mostly". And all those things you mention are pre-programmed actions, the machine is not determining a new course of action by itself. What was 60 years ago does not change the fact that today the scientific community defines "autonomous" something that has the answer "yes" to the question "Can this machine complete any full mission, with all possible emergency scenarios, without any human intervention except switching it on?" If not it's either only partially autonomous or simply automatic.

Answer (score 3):

Even the most modern aircraft autopilots of today are unable to be "autonomous".

The aircraft can not be programmed to takeoff or land by itself. Auto landings are possible, but only with inputs by the pilot.

The routing can be data linked to the aircraft, but it still needs the pilot to press the button to load it into the flight computer. After takeoff the A/P can follow the programmed route, but it is unable to climb or descend without input from the pilot. Any change in the routing (like avoiding thunderstorms) must be manually inputted by the pilot.

Currently, nothing can currently be done remotely. Remote control could be designed into an airliner, but it just hasn't been done yet, and probably never will.